# Netbeans Logger

Tags: java, netbeans, logging

I've been developping using Netbeans as an IDE for Java. When Netbeans surrounds a statement within a try-catch block it uses something like `Logger.getLogger(MyTestClass.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);` in the catch region. My questions are

1. What and where is the log file created by this sentence?
2. Should I create it? If so, how?

Cheers !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The logger is always available. You can create one with a custom name.
You write the logging to a file (with FileHandler):

```
Logger logger = Logger.getLogger("MyLog"); 
fh = new FileHandler("C:/temp/test/MyLogFile.log");  
logger.addHandler(fh);
```

By default logging is written to the console.
you can enable java console: http://www.java.com/en/download/help/javaconsole.xml

hope it helps