# Impossible to change netbeans logging level

Tags: java, macos, logging, netbeans, netbeans-7

This shouldn't be so complicated... change netbeans default logging level.

Despite the fact that english isn't my primary language, until now, I thought that I had a good understanding of it. Every post that I read states that is simple and easy to change it... But I can't manage to change it. By default, my netbeans starts logging at INFO level. I'm trying to lower it to FINEST.

I did a small POC, starting a brand new java application:

```
package javaapplication16;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.LogManager;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

public class JavaApplication16 {

    private static final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(JavaApplication16.class.getName());

    public static void main(String[] args) {        
        logger.log(Level.INFO, "hello!");
    }
}
```

It works fine. "hello!" is printed in netbeans output window. It also works for higher levels (WARNING, SEVERE).

But if I change it to FINE (or any other lower level). It didn't work.

I did everything that that I found on internet.

I changed main to

```
System.setProperty("javaapplication16.level", "100");
System.setProperty("javaapplication16.JavaApplication16", "100");
System.setProperty("java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler.level", "100");
try {
    LogManager.getLogManager().readConfiguration();
} catch (IOException | SecurityException ex) {
    logger.log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
}

logger.log(Level.FINE, "hello!");
```

Changed netbeans.conf and added `-J-Djavaapplication16.level=100` (and others). Created a **logging.properties** at app root level, etc... Neither alone or combined they worked.

Please, could you help me, point me out what I'm doing wrong?

My environment is:

```
Product Version: NetBeans IDE 7.2 (Build 201207171143)
Java: 1.7.0_07; Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM 23.3-b01
System: Mac OS X version 10.8.2 running on x86_64; US-ASCII; en_US (nb)
```

Posts that I found useful, but didn't worked for me:

- http://wiki.netbeans.org/DevFaqLogging
- [Netbeans Logger](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9744295/netbeans-logger)
- [netbeans logging tutorial](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10189464/netbeans-logging-tutorial)
- [How to logging output in console to file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5882868/how-to-logging-output-in-console-to-file)

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I also cannot figure out how to change the logging level in NetBeans. Should be a simple thing, and no one knows how.

Comment: @10flow unfortunately not. I left the company that I was working for, and at the new company, they use another IDE.

Answer (score 2):

I ran into the same problems...
My solution (finally) was to create a logging config file:

```
handlers = java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler
java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler.level = ALL
```

and set it up to the project running options:

```
>Project
>Properties
>Run
>VM Options: -Djava.util.logging.config.file=/home/myuser/logging.properties
```

Note the absolute path to the properties file, since I was not able to not load it from the running classpath (tried default project folder, default packaged, inside a package... and nothing), maybe that was happening when you were trying to load the properties file, given it's difficult some times to correctly determine where is located the current classpath.
I based myself on [this thread](https://forums.netbeans.org/topic24305.html) for the solution.
Netbeans version 7.2 and JDK jdk1.7.0_21.

Comment: Would be a great solution but sadly it doesn't do anything when applying it to a project in Netbeans 15, JDK 11

Answer (score 1):

The ConsoleHandler has a level also so I allocated a new ConsoleHandler and
set both the Logger and ConsoleHandler to the desired level. That worked!

```
    private static final Logger myLogger=Logger.getLogger(OrderApiClientJersey2_51_1.class.getName());
    static
    {
        // Default consoleHandler and Logger only log at INFO level
        Handler consoleHandler = new ConsoleHandler();  
        consoleHandler.setLevel(Level.ALL);
        myLogger.setLevel(Level.ALL);
        myLogger.addHandler(consoleHandler);
        myLogger.log(Level.FINEST, "Test Output");
    }
```

Comment: Was searching for quite a while and this one actually worked for me with Netbeans 15.

Answer (score 0):

```
 System.setProperty("java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler.level", "FINER");
```

You need to use the strings representing the levels, rather than their numeric equivalents. That line is copy-pasted from working code using JUL. I've since found that [log4j](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/) is a far better framework for logging in Java.

Comment: Thanks for replying, but didn't work. None of them: ALL, FINEST or FINER.